# add new column to an existing table with addition

Tags: sql, postgresql

given below is my table that i want calculate according to the `productid`

```
  +-----------+-----------+----------+
 'productid   |     free  |  qty     |
 '------------+-----------+----------+
 '     2372   |      0    |    100   |
 '------------+-----------+----------+
 '     2311   |      0    |    100   |
 '------------+-----------+----------+
 '     2311   |      1    |     10   |
 '------------------------------------
```

and  i need to get the following result

```
  +----------- +-----------+
 'productid   |     toqty  |  
 '------------+-----------+
 '     2372   |     100    |    
 '------------+-----------+
 '     2311   |     110    |     
 '-------------------------+
```

what i have tried is .

```
select sum(qty) as totQty 
from tmpprch 
where productid=(select productid from tmpprch)
```

and stuck here (`ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`)

`database : PostgreSQL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you are overcomplicating your query.  This is a simple aggregation:

```
select productid, sum(qty) as totQty
from tmpprch
group by productid;
```

Where did you get the idea for your form of the query?

Comment: @friend . . . I asked because `join` and `group by` seem more "basic" than subqueries.  I encourage you to keep learning.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Group By** clause. 
Here is some important links http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Here is simple Query

```
SELECT productid, SUM(qty) AS totQty
FROM tmpprch
Group By productid;
```